# В сноске «См.» или «См.:»

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно писать в сноске указание на книгу: с двоеточием или без? Какие из этих сносок оформлены верно?

1. См. *Розенталь Д. Э.* Справочник...
2. См.: *Розенталь Д. Э.* Справочник...
3. См. также *Даль В.* Словарь...
4. См. также: *Даль В.* Словарь...
5. См. Быт. 1:1.
6. См.: Ин. 1:1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

См. - это условное сокращение от слова "смотри(те)".

Двоеточие после "см." ставится по тем же правилам, что и после "смотри".
А именно, если ссылка строится по схеме "Автор. Название", то двоеточие ставится.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

cм. : Дитерихс М. К. Убийство Царской Семьи членов Дома Романовых на Урале. М., 1991.

См. : http: //forum.vgd.ru/994/44348/0.htm; http: //sverdport.lg.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?

См. : Гиацинтова С. С памятью наедине

Примеры без двоеточия (тоже из Нацкорпуса):

см. таблицу

см. в № 22 «Огонька»

см. «Сам себе робототехник» в «Эксперте» № 26 за 2014 год

см. "Локомотив" N 5, 2001 г.

см. "Чонкин" Войновича

см. "Начала" Евклида

Считаю правильными варианты 2, 4 и 5 из вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

См. - это условное сокращение от слова "смотри(те)". В сносках оно является сказуемым, соответственно никаких оснований ставить после него двоеточия нет.